# How to put axios data into v-select by v-for?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I used axios to get multiple lines of data,
and then I wanted to put the data in v-select so that others could choose, 
I thought of using v-for to make him print out line by line. 
But the result shows no data available.

my code

```
<template>
  <div>
     <v-select :item="desserts.name"></v-select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    desserts: [
      {
        id: "",
        name: ""
      }
    ]
  }),
  created() {
    this.getprotifile();
  },
  methods: {
    getprotifile() {
      this.axios
        .get("/api/admin/categories")
        .then(res => {
          //console.table(res.data);
          this.desserts = res.data;
          //console.log(this.desserts);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        })
        .finally(() => {});
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for the vuetify v-select component for `:items="deserts"` (notice items plural) you would need to have an array of objects like

```
deserts: [
    {text: "The name", value:"the ID"},
    ...
]
```

or you can use the directives

```
item-text="name"
item-value="id"
```

and then your :items object can look like

```
[{"id": 1,"name": "aaa"}, {"id": 4,"name": "bbb"}, {"id": 5,"name": "ccc"}, {"id": 9,"name": "ddd"}]
```

You can use the map method if you need to map the data from the server in to the correct format

```
this.selectOptions = resp.data.options.map(options => ({value: option.id, text: option.name}));
```

Answer (score 0):

`desserts` is an array, so it doesn't have the `name` property, as written in your template.

Probably `<v-select :item="desserts"></v-select>` is just fine.

Please, look at the official vuetify doc in order to understand which props pass to `v-select` to make it work correctly: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/

Comment: I have two sets of data, and I want people to choose the name of the data
[{"id": 1,"name": "aaa"},
 {"id": 4,"name": "bbb"},
 {"id": 5,"name": "ccc"},
 {"id": 9,"name": "ddd"}]

Answer (score 0):

I guess this one can solve the problem:

```
<v-select :item="desserts.filter(item => item.name)"></v-select>
```